# Recursively Download All Files in a Web Directory Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to recursively download all files of a certain file extension `(.csv)` from a password-protected web directory using `PowerShell`. I thought that I would be able to achieve this by using an asterisk `*` as a wildcard, though as I am trying to test this out, this does not appear to be the case.

**Powershell Script (somescript.ps1):**

```
$currdate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$Username = 'username'
$Password = 'password'

$url1 = "http://some.website/somedirectory/"+$currdate+"/csv/*.csv"

$url1

$path1 = "D:\somedirectory\someotherdirectory\*.csv"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username,$Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile($url1,$path1 )
```

**Error Message:**

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At C:\Users\someuser\somescript.ps1:13 char:1
+ $WebClient.DownloadFile($url1,$path1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use wildcards for an Argument to a .Net method and here , you have to give absolute path to the File, for both URL and Save location

Comment: Are you in control of the target web directory?

Comment: Get the site to provide a list of the full urls all the files to be downloaded and then download and save each in turn

Comment: Thanks for chiming in PRASOON KARUNAN V and @Nkosi. I have full control of the website.